# How to integrate JSP with SOLR?

Tags: jsp, solr

I have created a simple JSP page that consist of textbox and search button. So when user types in something, it should call SOLR to query the data and return results back to the JSP page.

I had searched through the net for days.
Looked through the [SolrJava](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava) guide, but I don't understand what it means by handler and the SolrJ code, my solr root folder does not have any "org" folder (I download solr-4.7.0 that starts off with "contrib", "dist", "docs", "example", "licenses" and some text files).

Could anyone enlighten me, how do you use JSP to call SOLR? Any step by step explanation or link will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

solr can be called via a simple HTTP-GET Request. You can use that from the shell via curl or use a similiar object in java. If you go to the solr-console, that can be found here:
YOUR-URL:8983/solr/ you can query the machine. The URL, that you need to call from your JSP is shown 
above the field, where the answers are shown.

Comment: So let's say if I need to query "source_t:CNA", then in JSP I need to link to the URL http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=source_t%3Acna. Am I right?

Comment: well ... localhost just works on your machine, if you have a server somewhere or someone wants to check out your code, that would not be working. also, the "q" param is the queried value, df should be the field, so i guess the url should be 
YOUR_IP:8983/solr/collection1/select?df=source_t%3Acna&q=VALUE_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR